# Test suite Run time in karate in report

Tags: report, karate

I am using karate 9.0.0 and running feature files in parallel and generating 
 cucumber report using karate parallel run code. Problem is that in the report in feature overview its showing the total time execution as

**feature 1 execution time + feature 2 execution time +feature 3 execution time = total execution time**

but actual execution time is less if i am running features in parallel in more than 1 thread. How can i show and calculate the test suite run time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is reported on the console. I don't understand why you need to worry about it as long as your tests are running reasonably fast.

Anyway, if you really want to capture this, just use the methods of the [`Results`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-core/src/main/java/com/intuit/karate/Results.java) class that you get from the `Runner.parallel()`. For example you have a `getElapsedTime()` method.

Comment: it works for me. test suite run reports we need to submit to higher leadership and they are concerned about test suite Run, although its fast enough :) and they are looking into one line run time and results

Comment: my question is it possible to show getElapsedTime() at feature overview html page?

Comment: @KarateCoder there may be a hack, you can change the name, where you see `"demo"` here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/DemoTestParallel.java