# Fetching Total Execution time when parallel execution enabled and execution done through maven command

Tags: karate

My problem is kind of same as in this post - [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56116495/test-suite-run-time-in-karate-in-report). My management is also concerned about the total execution time as number of scenarios going to be more in coming days, so it would be great if I can showcase Total execution time on cucumber report. Please find my stats below

[image: Contains karate stats]

By using `getElapsedTime()` from Results, I am getting is 17.39 seconds

By using `getTimeTakenMillis()` from Results, I am getting is 240.39 seconds

My question is, why elapsed time(17.39 seconds) and total time(1:03 min- Under BUILD SUCCESS) is having so much difference?

And Actual time of execution I am looking for is 1:03 min which is being displayed as Total time under "BUILD SUCCESS". How can I fetch this value to display on cucumber report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elapsed time is counted only when the test-suite starts. If your maven build was stuck downloading dependencies, that will explain the difference.

If your management is so concerned, please ask them to consider contributing code to fix any potential issues. This is an open-source project.

Comment: thanks for the response. Do you mean to say that all 233 scenarios are getting executed in 17.39 seconds in my case?

Comment: @meghaclr maybe :) you are in the best position to investigate !

Comment: Sure, will look into it then. But I 1 thing is correct, my script execution definitely not taking more than 1:03 mins so I can't consider "thread time" which is 240 seconds.

Comment: In that case, could you help me understand what is thread time(240 seconds) then? @Peter Thomas

Comment: @meghaclr you are running 16 threads. it is quite likely the tests are being run in 17 seconds. the thread time is the time of all tests added up. also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58048260/143475

Comment: Accepting the answer as I got clarity. That post was helpful to understand about efficiency though. thanks.

Comment: haha.. I can explain them about elapsed time now, I am sure they will accept. :D